# How to best manage repeated sections on a page other than master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC, you have master pages for your layout, and you can create partial views for re-usable sections of your website.

The problem with partial views is that in every controller action, your Model has to have all the properties/data required to pass on to your partials.  This isn't a big deal but at times it does get cumbersome if you have many partials.

What other options are there?

Comment: Can you provide examples of when a partial view doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: @Eckert It isn't that it doesn't meet my expectations, so I have 5 components on my page, I have to now load all the data for those 5 components and add it to each model.  And then on each page I have to setup those partials and pass in the model for them.

Comment: As Alexei points out, you should use child actions. Also, don't call them "master pages". That's only for Web Forms, and since MVC can work with Web Forms, it confuses your meaning when speaking of layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that controller need to prepare all (or even any) data in top level model for every partial. Caller itself can prepare model just fine:

```
 @Html.Partial("QuestionView", new Topic { Question="Why", Answer = "Because"});
```

You can also call any other controller action from the view and pass any data you like:

```
 @Html.Action("Left", controllerName:"Arrows", 
      routeValues: new {ArrowLength = 5});

 class ArrowsController
 {
    [ChildAction] // add this if never called as top level action via url
    ActionResult Left(int arrowLength)
    { ....
         return View("Arrow", new ArrowModel(ArrowDir.Left, arrowLength * 7);
    }
```

The only real problem with ASP.Net MVC up to 5 is that you can't make proper `async` calls from view - like if your partial view or child action needs to query remote database or service you would basically have to do the call from top level controller. View components in vNext removes that restriction.

Comment: When I call Html.Action, is it making a separate http request?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand, if my childAction needs to query the database I can't do that currently?

Comment: @coolbreeze: Not a separate request, no. Although it still goes through the MVC routing pipeline.

Comment: @coolbreeze no. It just finds controller/action combination through regular routing and renders result in place.

Comment: @coolbreeze: You can do anything in a child action that you could in a normal action. You just can't do it asynchronously. In other words, for Entity Framework, you could only use something like `SingleOrDefault`, not `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

Comment: @coolbreeze "you can't make proper *async* calls from view" - indeed you can query DB or whatever from child view as long as you make synchronous calls (like `cmd.ExecuteReader` and not `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync`)

Comment: ah ok, I got it.  But like you said, if I have 2 Html.Action calls on a page, it will make 3 http requests in total right?  1 is the page itself, and one each for each call to http.action.  Is that correct?

Comment: @coolbreeze: not requests, per se. This is not like AJAX on page actually making a request and waiting for a response. It goes through the routing framework and is handled like a request, but there's no network communication and no latency.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Interesting, so it somehow combines the 2 action requests into a single call.

Comment: @coolbreeze: Not really. We're about to get into "extended discussion" territory, but essentially the pipleline is like this. Initial request is routed to action. The action returns a view. Razor comes in to parse the view file. In do so, if finds a call to `Html.Action`. This is just method like any other. However, the method hooks into the routing framework to find and call the child action, which itself returns a view that Razor also parses. Remember that an action, too, is just a method, and can be called completely outside of a request.